# How to Install Nvidia Drivers: problems with keyboard

Tags: console, nvidia

I'm trying to install Nvidia drivers on an old version of Linux: CentOS 6.4.  When I exit the X server with 'init 3', it puts me into a login prompt.  However whenever I type anything, the keyboard input is messed up.  'r' becomes '^R', o becomes '^O', etc.  Does this sound familiar?

If I modify /etc/inittab to boot into run level 3, I get the same problem.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a workaround for the problem.  I had a few other USB devices on this PC.  I disconnected those devices and the problem went away.  I don't know exactly what caused the problem, but it works for me.